# Bash syntax error: line 7: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

So I have a bash script

```
!#/bin/bash 
while [ true ];do
ls -lah /sth/ | grep sth*
sleep 0.001
done
exit 0
```

I thoought thai it was ok but when I run it I get

> line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

But the code has only 6 lines?
What may be a problem? I edited the file in linux, deleted unnecessary spaces but still my scropt doesn't work.

Comment: It is `#!/bin/bash` instead of `!#`.

Comment: You might need a space after the semi colon: `while [ true ]; do`. The shell is very temperamental at times.

Answer (score 1):

The [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is wrong.  You are not running it under Bash at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Notice the order of the sharp (`#`) and the bang (`!`).